# 人間というのは、余程嫌いな相手でない限り

Tags: meaning

> 人間というのは、余程嫌いな相手でない限り、相手の短所より長所のほうに目が行くよう出来ていることが、さまざまな心理実験で明らかにされている、いわゆる「隣の芝部は青い」現象である

I do get the majority of the meaning of this sentence except the beginning part:

> 人間というのは、余程嫌いな相手でない限り

Does this mean: In regards to Humans: There is a limit as to how much a human dislikes another humanoid?

Continuing on:

The opponent (or other person) strong points rather than weak points are looked at by humanoid 1, and this phenomenon is called the grass is always green/blue on the other side.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

...限り in this case means "as long as ..." (see definition 4 of 限り on jisho.org: https://jisho.org/search/kagiri).

So I would translate 余程嫌いな相手でない限り as "as long as it's not someone [subject] very much hates". The whole sentence would be something along the lines of:

"The fact that humans are made in a way that they - as long as they don't very much hate someone - draw their eyes towards others' strong points rather than their weaknesses is the so-called "the grass is always greener on the other side" phenomenon, which has been made evident by various psychological experiments."